# Resulting type of object literal

Tags: typescript, specifications

From specification:

*When an object literal is contextually typed by a type that includes a string index signature, the resulting type of the object literal includes a string index signature with the union type of the types of the properties declared in the object literal, or the Undefined type if the object literal is empty*

What does it mean - **the resulting type of the object literal**?

Let say we have

```
var a:{[key:string]:any} = {a:1,b:"2"};
```

`a` has type `{[key:string]:any}`

Where is the resulting type of object literal in this declaration?

Is there any places in code where I can see resulting type of object literal in action?

Comment: It looks like it's about the type for `this` in the methods defined in the object literal, if it has any. If so, it's obsolete since [`this` in object literal methods is inferred as `any`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8389). The spec has not seen any commits since 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any places in code where I can see resulting type of object literal in action?

Following code sample

```
declare const str: 'a' | 'b';
let foo = { a: 1, b: "2" }[str]; // typeof foo is string | number
```

Comment: where is the type that includes a string index signature in right hand expression?

Comment: By the way, from spec: _If index is a string literal or a numeric literal and object has an apparent property (section 3.11.1) with the name given by that literal (converted to its string representation in the case of a numeric literal), the property access is of the type of that property._ If `str` is **string literal** then `foo` has type of apparent member that are not `string|number`. But `str` is union and spec doesn't consider this case.